# Why lock Prevents Timer Overlap

Tags: c#

I was wondering how using `lock` prevents the System.Threading.Timer from overlapping the portion of code inside the `lock` statement but not the code outside it! ?, how is it working.

Comment: That sounds like a nasty way of backing work up in the ThreadPool and causing thread-pool starvation. IMO, locking in the ThreadPool is harmful. If overlap is a risk/problem, ditch the periodic timer and instead, schedule one-time timers (`Timeout.Infinite`), do your work, then reschedule another one-time timer (and so on...).

Comment: i was asking just about the mechanism that enabled lock statement to do that

Comment: A lock blocks code.  It is like you trying to enter a room through a door.  Whomever was ahead entered the room and locked that door.  You can't get in, your stuck waiting at the door.  Until that person leaves and unlocks the door.  And you lock it again.  There will only ever be one person in the room.

Comment: @HansPassant: very well answer!

Comment: please try to take a look at this link   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163744.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx

Comment: I really don't know what is wrong with my very simple, yet ideal for me [and maybe for some other people], question ?!... why people just come and vote me down! i think `Hans Passant`, `Jon Skeet` easily got me a very well detailed answers in a matter of seconds, which means that my question is very clear, and not very wide as some one just reported it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably because you've got multiple threads locking on the same object.

The whole point of a `lock` statement is that only one thread can acquire any particular monitor at a time. If they didn't do that, they'd be pretty pointless! If your timer threads were to try to acquire *different* monitors, they'd all be able to run concurrently.

If that doesn't help, please read [MSDN on the `lock` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), and then post a more specific question if you're still confused.

Comment: So you mean the every System.Threading.Timer loop creates a new thread to run the callback code ?

Comment: @RuneS: Timer callbacks queued in the ThreadPool (which is a collection of Threads that are used by all sorts of things in .NET). When a thread is available, the threadpool will dequeue the work item (e.g. the delegate supplied to your Timer) and invoke it. The ThreadPool tries to keep the number of threads it holds close to the number of processors on your machine, and is slow to create new ones. If you spend a lot of time locking in the work item, the threadpool will take longer to process items in the work queue as it spins up extra threads to deal with queues that are backing-up.

Comment: Well detailed now i understand what is going on and i fixed my library so i now run the timer on demand...